# Trying to Display Results between Two Dates Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters, ng-filter

I am trying to search based on title, TicketId, date range (from to)

Not all search inputs need to be filled.

If a person entered the first date only, It will return output with that date
if both dates are entered, then it will print all results between both dates

Ignore the CSS file.I added it to show you how it should look like

Also, How can I add a reset button to remove all data written in the input?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('engsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.orderProperty = "Title";
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.userInput = {};
  $scope.worktime = [{
      Title: "basil@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:00",
      WorkLog: "adfadf",
      TicketId: 17554
    },
    {
      Title: "Jake@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:30",
      WorkLog: "-",
      TicketId: 17554
    },
    {
      Title: "Jessica@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:00",
      WorkLog: "-",
      TicketId: 175540
    },
    {
      Title: "Sulaiman@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:00",
      WorkLog: "-",
      TicketId: 175540
    },
    {
      Title: "Mohammed@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:00",
      WorkLog: null,
      TicketId: 175540
    },
    {
      Title: "Ann@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:00",
      WorkLog: null,
      TicketId: 175540
    },
    {
      Title: "Ahmed@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/21 00:00",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/21 01:00",
      TravelTime: "01:00",
      ProcureTime: "01:15",
      WorkLog: "-",
      TicketId: 17554
    },
    {
      Title: "Sarah@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/21 10:57",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/22 10:57",
      TravelTime: "00:00",
      ProcureTime: "00:00",
      WorkLog: "-",
      TicketId: 17554
    },
    {
      Title: "Dalal@email.com",
      TimeIn: "2017\/11\/26 9:48",
      TimeOut: "2017\/11\/26 01:45",
      TravelTime: "00:00",
      ProcureTime: "00:00",
      WorkLog: "hgkjhg",
      TicketId: 17555
    }
  ]

  $scope.applySearch = function() {
    for (prop in $scope.userInput) {
      $scope.search[prop] = $scope.userInput[prop];

    }
  };
  
  $scope.deleteData=function(){
            $scope.userInput.Title="";
            $scope.userInput.TimeOut="";
            $scope.userInput.TimeIn="";
            $scope.userInput.TicketId="";
            for(prop in $scope.userInput) {    
                $scope.search[prop] = $scope.userInput[prop];   
            }
         };


  $scope.setOrderProperty = function(propertyName) {
    if ($scope.orderProperty === propertyName) {
      $scope.orderProperty = '-' + propertyName;
    } else if ($scope.orderProperty === '-' + propertyName) {
      $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    } else {
      $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    }
  };


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.navbar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
}


/*
headeer top
*/

.topbar {
  background-color: #212529;
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar .container .row {
  margin: -7px;
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar .container .row .col-md-12 {
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #f1f6ff;
}

.topbar p>i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.topbar p:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

header .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.topbar li.topbar {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 18px;
  line-height: 52px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.topbar li.topbar:hover {
  color: #1bbde8;
}

.topbar ul.info i {
  color: #131313;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.topbar ul.info li {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 44px;
}

.topbar ul.info i span {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

a {
  color: #0a0a0a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bg-image-full {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #222!important;
}

.mx-background-top-linear {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
}

table {
  font-weight: 400;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

th a {
  display: block;
  /* Making the headerlinks 100% width */
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* Making the headerlinks 100% height ??? */
  height: 100%;
  /* doesnt work! */
  min-height: 100%;
}

tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='app'>


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mx-background-top-linear">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="text-transform: uppercase;"> WorkTimings</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!--filters -->


    <div ng-controller="engsCtrl">
      <h1>Table Sheet</h1>
      <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.Title' placeholder="Search by title" />
              <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TicketId' placeholder="Search by TicketId" />
              <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TimeIn' placeholder="Search by Start Date" />
              <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TimeOut' placeholder="Search by EndDate" />
              <button ng-click="applySearch()">Search</button>
              <button ng-click="deleteData()">Reset</button>
      <table id="example" class="table  table-hover table-light ">
        <thead class="thead-grey" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('Title')">Title &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TimeIn')">TimeIn &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TimeOut')">TimeOut &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TravelTime')">TravelTime &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('ProcureTime')">ProcureTime &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('WorkLog')">WorkLog &#8645;</a></th>
            <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TicketId')">TicketId &#8645;</a></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
          <tr ng-repeat="x in worktime | orderBy : orderProperty | filter:search">
            <th scope="row">{{ x.Title }}</th>
            <td>{{ x.TimeIn }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TimeOut }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TravelTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.ProcureTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.WorkLog }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.TicketId }}</td>



          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>




    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>



</body>



</html>
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following:

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {
       
        var filtered = [];
        if (fromDate==='' && toDate==='')
            return items;
     
        //here you will have your desired input
        
        var from_date =fromDate!==''? new Date(fromDate):"0001/01/01";
        var to_date = to_date !== '' ? new Date(toDate) : "9999/30/12";
        if (fromDate !== '' && toDate !== '') {
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var timeIn = new Date(item.TimeIn);
                var timeOut = new Date(item.TimeOut);
                if ((timeIn >= from_date && timeOut <= to_date)) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }


            });
        }
        if (fromDate !== '' && toDate === '') {
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var timeIn = new Date(item.TimeIn);
                var timeOut = new Date(item.TimeOut);
                if (timeIn >= from_date) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            });
        }
        if (fromDate === '' && toDate !== '') {
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var timeIn = new Date(item.TimeIn);
                var timeOut = new Date(item.TimeOut);
                if (timeIn <= to_date) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            });
        }

        return filtered;
    };
});
app.controller('engsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.orderProperty = "Title";
    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.userInput = {};
    $scope.worktime = [
        {
            Title: "basil@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:00" ,
            WorkLog: "adfadf" ,
            TicketId: 17554
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Jake@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:30" ,
            WorkLog: "-" ,
            TicketId: 17554
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Jessica@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:00" ,
            WorkLog: "-" ,
            TicketId: 175540
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Sulaiman@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:00" ,
            WorkLog: "-" ,
            TicketId: 175540
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Mohammed@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:00" ,
            WorkLog: null ,
            TicketId: 175540
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Ann@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/08 00:45" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/08 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:00" ,
            WorkLog: null ,
            TicketId: 175540
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Ahmed@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/21 00:00" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/21 01:00" ,
            TravelTime: "01:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "01:15" ,
            WorkLog: "-" ,
            TicketId: 17554
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Sarah@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/21 10:57" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/22 10:57" ,
            TravelTime: "00:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "00:00" ,
            WorkLog: "-" ,
            TicketId: 17554
        } ,
        {
            Title: "Dalal@email.com" ,
            TimeIn: "2017\/11\/26 9:48" ,
            TimeOut: "2017\/11\/26 01:45" ,
            TravelTime: "00:00" ,
            ProcureTime: "00:00" ,
            WorkLog: "hgkjhg" ,
            TicketId: 17555
        }
    ];
    $scope.userInput.TimeIn = '';
    $scope.userInput.TimeOut= '';
    $scope.applySearch = function () {
        for (prop in $scope.userInput) {
            $scope.search[prop] = $scope.userInput[prop];
           

        }

        console.log($scope.search);
    };
    $scope.deleteData = function () {
        $scope.userInput.Title = "";
        $scope.userInput.TimeOut = "";
        $scope.userInput.TimeIn = "";
        $scope.userInput.TicketId = "";
        $scope.applySearch();
    }

    $scope.setOrderProperty = function (propertyName) {
        if ($scope.orderProperty === propertyName) {
            $scope.orderProperty = '-' + propertyName;
        } else if ($scope.orderProperty === '-' + propertyName) {
            $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
        } else {
            $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
        }
    };


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.navbar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
}


/*
headeer top
*/

.topbar {
  background-color: #212529;
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar .container .row {
  margin: -7px;
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar .container .row .col-md-12 {
  padding: 0;
}

.topbar p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #f1f6ff;
}

.topbar p>i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.topbar p:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

header .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.topbar li.topbar {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 18px;
  line-height: 52px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.topbar li.topbar:hover {
  color: #1bbde8;
}

.topbar ul.info i {
  color: #131313;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.topbar ul.info li {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 44px;
}

.topbar ul.info i span {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

a {
  color: #0a0a0a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bg-image-full {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #222!important;
}

.mx-background-top-linear {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #d4002e 48%, #1b1e21 48%);
}

table {
  font-weight: 400;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

th a {
  display: block;
  /* Making the headerlinks 100% width */
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* Making the headerlinks 100% height ??? */
  height: 100%;
  /* doesnt work! */
  min-height: 100%;
}

tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='app'>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



</head>


<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mx-background-top-linear">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="text-transform: uppercase;"> WorkTimings</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                Home
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>


                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <!--filters -->


        <div ng-controller="engsCtrl">
            <h1>Table Sheet</h1>
            <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.Title' placeholder="Search by title" />
            <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TicketId' placeholder="Search by TicketId" />
            <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TimeIn' placeholder="Search by Start Date" />
            <input type='text' ng-model='userInput.TimeOut' placeholder="Search by EndDate" />
            
            <button ng-click="deleteData()">Delete</button>
            <table id="example" class="table  table-hover table-light ">
                <thead class="thead-grey" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('Title')">Title &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TimeIn')">TimeIn &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TimeOut')">TimeOut &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TravelTime')">TravelTime &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('ProcureTime')">ProcureTime &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('WorkLog')">WorkLog &#8645;</a></th>
                        <th class="btn-secondary"><a ng-click="setOrderProperty('TicketId')">TicketId &#8645;</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody align="center">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in worktime  | dateRange : userInput.TimeIn : userInput.TimeOut|orderBy : orderProperty | filter:userInput.Title:TravelTime:ProcureTime:WorkLog:TicketId ">
                        <th scope="row">{{ x.Title }}</th>
                        <td>{{ x.TimeIn }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.TimeOut }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.TravelTime }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.ProcureTime }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.WorkLog }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.TicketId }}</td>



                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>




        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>



</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but you only solved the delete input from the <input> area but it is not resetting the table. I still have the issue for the date range that hasn't been solved in your code

Comment: Thank you. Yes I found the solution. The most important part is the date. If you can help me with it, I will be so thankful for you

Comment: I modify my answer.I add a filter named dateRange and use it in view...please check my answer if reach to your answer

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. That is why I am not able to figure out a solution for the problem

Comment: Can you show me? Cause it isn't working for me. I entered 2017/11/07 as FromDate & 2017/11/22 as a toDate. It returned nothing and all data from the table was removed

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand  your question truly.but i change code and test again and it did work truly.please test again

Comment: Wops found a smal bug though. TicketId doesn't work anymore

Comment: Found a solution for the TicketId issue. no need to fix your code unless if you want to